# Outlook 2010 signatures profile dissapearing

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, signature, citrix, roaming-profile

I am working on a service desk/position, not too long though, and this morning when I logged in on my machine and on my company citrix machine I tried to reply from citrix and I suddenly realize that my signature profile has disapeared.

When I asked my colleagues if they have had the same issue they said yes, so I started to search for some kind of a resolution but the only one that made sense was a resolution for the problem on Oulook 2003.

On 2003 installation Outlook creates a registry key named 'first run' or something like that and if you work with more than one server like I do when I connect to the citrix machine and if the value is different from server to server, outlook seems to think that you are on your first run and creates you a new profile. So the fix on 2003 is that you need to set the same value to the first run key on all citrix servers.

But 2010 seems that it doesn`t create the reg key that I mentioned earlier so if someone can help me with this I will really appreciate it! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691977 Might help to just have the signature automaically set up for all users